# How to Creatie Multiple Site Collections and Subsites under a already Created fresh Web Application. Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sitecollection, sharepoint-object-model

I have a fresh web application already created.

Now I just want to Programmatically add Site Collections and Subsites to the Web Application  using the console application.

Any Help appreciated.

Regards,
Navish

Answer (score 0):

You can use next class for your needs. Please adapt it and fill exceptions handling blocks.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows to create site collections and web sites.
    /// </summary>
    public class SiteCreation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates new site collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="webApplicationsUrl">Web application url, which will host new site collection.</param>
        /// <param name="siteUrl">Created site collection URL.</param>
        /// <param name="siteTitle">Created site collection title.</param>
        /// <param name="siteDescription">Created site collection description.</param>
        /// <param name="siteTemplateName">Template name (STS#0 for example).</param>
        /// <param name="lcid">LCID (1033 for English).</param>
        /// <param name="ownerLogin">Owner login name.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Created site collection.
        /// </returns>
        public SPSite CreateSiteUnderWebApplication(string webApplicationsUrl, string siteUrl, string siteTitle, string siteDescription, string siteTemplateName, uint lcid, string ownerLogin)
        {
            var webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(webApplicationsUrl));
            if (webApp != null)
            {
                using (var site = webApp.Sites[siteUrl])
                {
                    if (site == null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var siteNew = webApp.Sites.Add(siteUrl, siteTitle, siteDescription, lcid, siteTemplateName, ownerLogin, ownerLogin, string.Empty);
                            return siteNew;
                        }
                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                            //error can't create site
                            //if (Properties.Settings.Default.logErrorMessages)
                            //    eventLog.WriteEntry(exc.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // warning site already exist
                        //if (Properties.Settings.Default.logWarningMessages)
                        //    eventLog.WriteEntry("Site: " + strSiteUrl + " under webapp: " + strWebApplicationsUrl + " alredy exist.", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // error can't access webapp
                //if (Properties.Settings.Default.logErrorMessages)
                //    eventLog.WriteEntry("Can't access " + strWebApplicationsUrl + " webapp", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create web site under site collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="siteCollectionUrl">URL of parent site collection.</param>
        /// <param name="webSiteUrl">Url of created web site.</param>
        /// <param name="webSiteTitle">Title of created web site.</param>
        /// <param name="webSiteDescription">Description of created web site.</param>
        /// <param name="webSiteTemplateName">Name of web site template.</param>
        /// <param name="lcid">LCID of web site.</param>
        /// <param name="isCustomTemplate">True if webSiteTemplateName is name of custom template.</param>
        /// <returns>Created web site.</returns>
        public SPWeb CreateWebSiteUnderSiteCollection(string siteCollectionUrl, string webSiteUrl, string webSiteTitle, string webSiteDescription, string webSiteTemplateName, uint lcid, bool isCustomTemplate)
        {
            SPSite siteCollection = null;
            SPWeb web = null;
            try
            {
                siteCollection = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl);
                web = siteCollection.AllWebs[webSiteUrl];
                if (web.Exists)
                {
                    // warning site already exist
                    //if (Properties.Settings.Default.logWarningMessages)
                    //    eventLog.WriteEntry("Site: " + strSiteUrl + " under site collection: " + strSiteCollectionUrl + " alredy exist.", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    web.Dispose();
                    web = siteCollection.OpenWeb();
                    siteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPWeb webNew = null;
                    if (isCustomTemplate)
                    {
                        var siteTemplate = siteCollection.GetCustomWebTemplates(lcid)[webSiteTemplateName];
                        webNew = web.Webs.Add(webSiteUrl, webSiteTitle, webSiteDescription, lcid, siteTemplate, false, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        webNew = web.Webs.Add(webSiteUrl, webSiteTitle, webSiteDescription, lcid, webSiteTemplateName, false, false);
                    }
                    siteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    return webNew;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //error can't create site
                //if (Properties.Settings.Default.logErrorMessages)
                //    eventLog.WriteEntry(exc.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (web != null)
                    web.Dispose();
                if (siteCollection != null)
                    siteCollection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```